# The file name is not valid. Check the file name for the database. [ File name = file:\C:\Users\

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I have a `windows CE` application that uses `SQL CE` and `.Net3.5` in MS VS 2008.
when I run my application **in mobile emulator every thing is OK** and mobile application works fine.

But when I run `application.exe` in `Debug` folder **on my PC I see the error below!**
i Googled it , but couldn't find any solution.

have anybody got a solution for it?

This is my *LongLongAddress\MyMobileApp\bin\Debug* folder : 
[image]

[image]

Comment: So is that sdb file in your debug folder?

Comment: What is a .sdb file? I have the .sdf in debug folder as you can see in the picture above

Comment: @TonyHopkinson he is using sql Compact Edition, should he have a `.sdb` file?

Comment: You're trying to run the application, which was built for the CF, on a PC, not a device?  Why?

Comment: @ctacke , you right , the application haven't any problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I have a mistake that want to open a CF app on a PC !!! :)
when i create a .cab file and transmit it to CF device application worked fine.
I believed that before transmit the APP , test it on a PC , so i see that error.