# The file name is not valid. Check the file name for the database. [ File name = E:\\PractDB.sdf ]

Tags: sql-server-ce, connection-string, windows-ce

I know there is already a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435775/the-file-name-is-not-valid-check-the-file-name-for-the-database-file-name) for similar issue. However mine issue is on development computer itself.

We have a client requirement of developing database driven application for Motorola MC 65 (Window CE os) devices.

Following internet have been able to run a empty form application on the device (device attached to cradle).

I created a SQL Server Compact database, added a table and filled data into it. Through Visual Studio Server Explorer established connection successfully.

However through code I'm getting an error.

Below is my connection string code:

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection();

con.ConnectionString = @"Persist Security Info = False;
                         Data Source = 'E:\\PractDB.sdf';
                         Password = 'password#123'; 
                         File Mode = 'shared read'; 
                         Max Database Size = 256; 
                         Max Buffer Size = 1024";

con.Open();
```

Kindly let know what I am missing. What is the correct way to reference a `.sdf` database file in the connection string?

Comment: Normally on Windows CE you do not use drive letters

Answer (score 0):

The leading `@` character means you have an **unescaped** string. There is no escape character and backslash (`\`) doesn't do anything special.

So when you have this:

```
'E:\\PractDB.sdf'
```

both of those backslash characters are part of your string. Just get rid of one of them and you'll be fine, assuming that really is the right path and file.

Also, you shouldn't need the quote marks. Thus, the final connection string looks like this:

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Persist Security Info = False;
                         Data Source = E:\PractDB.sdf;
                         Password =password#123; 
                         File Mode = shared read; 
                         Max Database Size = 256; 
                         Max Buffer Size = 1024;";
```

But a quick Google check on that device shows it runs Windows Mobile 6.5. It's doubtful that the `E:\` drive is the correct path for this database or any database, as Windows Mobile never used drive letters. Unfortunately, I have to know more about how your app is deployed before I can give more specific information about what you should actually have here.

Answer (score 0):

Windows CE does not use drive letters.

If the database is stored in the root folder, simply use `\PractDB.sdf`.